# MySQL Join 2nd table with not Unique Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have got 2 Tables I need to query. I cannot unique values for the linked key.
The first Table stores stories or posts per child.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `learning_story` (
  `story_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `child_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `img_file` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `storydate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `teacher_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pro_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'draft',
  PRIMARY KEY (`story_id`),
  KEY `child_id` (`child_id`),
  KEY `pro_id` (`pro_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

Each story or post is unique to a child (child_id Foreign Key).
Now I am adding the ability to add posts that belong to a group of children.
Here are 4 sample rows

```
INSERT INTO `learning_story` (`story_id`, `child_id`, `img_file`, `title`, `description`, `link`, `storydate`, `teacher_id`, `pro_id`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 5, '', 'Story 1', '<p><img src="http://127.0.0.1/websites/my-books/assets/mercury_img/2dfeb1f41c48a308b7eee8526918ebb7.JPG" style="cursor: default; width: 222.28915662650604px; height: 125px; float: right; margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px; " alt=""></p><p><img src="http://127.0.0.1/websites/my-books/img/timbthumb.php?src=http://127.0.0.1/websites/my-books/assets/2/children/test_09.JPG&q=100&w=180&h=130" alt="imagetitle" style="cursor: default; ">dsd sdsdsd s ds ffdfdf </p>\r\n', '', '2012-10-08 20:42:05', 0, 2, 'draft'),
(12, 5, '', 'Teachers Final Test 33', '<p>ds sd sd sd sd  dsdsd dsd sd s </p><p><br></p><p>Tweety</p>\r\n', '', '2012-10-12 12:19:45', 31, 2, 'draft'),
(30, 6, '', 'Boys High Choir', '<p>sasassa</p>', '', '2012-10-14 09:55:08', 0, 2, 'draft'),
(32, 0, '', 'Story Not Mine ID 5', '<p>dsd sd sd s ds ds ds sd sd </p>\r\n', '', '2012-10-14 12:21:36', 0, 2, 'draft');
```

Among these there is 1 record that has a child_id set to 0. This record belongs to the child_id's in the 2nd table.

2nd table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `story_groups` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `child_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `story_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=112 ;



INSERT INTO `story_groups` (`id`, `child_id`, `story_id`) VALUES
(40, 7, 30),
(41, 8, 30),
(107, 8, 32),
(108, 9, 32),
(109, 11, 32),
(110, 12, 32),
(111, 5, 32);
```

So I want to get all stories/posts for a child. Including the Group Stories.

I have tried UNION matching and a bunch of JOIN combinations but I just cant crack it.

It is probably a simple JOIN operation which I just cant crack.

Could somebody please help me write my query to include the rows from the story_groups table?

Comment: Why not do away with the `child_id` column in the first table and relate all stories to their children solely through records in the second table?

Comment: After you point that out it makes perfect sense. Just had it setup without the group function and didnt want to change too much. Need to stop patching and RETHINK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT learning_story.*
FROM   learning_story LEFT JOIN story_groups USING (story_id)
WHERE  learning_story.child_id = ? OR story_groups.child_id = ?
```

Comment: Hey, that hit the spot! need to brush up on the sql.